# Login module doesn't login, redirects back to home page

Tags: joomla-2.5, module, login

For whatever reason, the login module in the frontend of my website has suddenly stopped working. Every attempt to login using it just redirects back to the home page without logging in the user, however any login attempt made by going to the component itself works just fine. There are non error messages at all, nothing from Joomla and nothing from forcefully showing PHP errors.

At first I thought it may have been my custom template for the module, but even after "restoring" the default version of the module, the problem persists.

I tried modifying the login authentication in `libraries/joomla/application/application.php` to do a test on the spot if the login was failing for unknown reasons, but the login attempts do not make it that far (unless the module uses a different method to authenticate logins).

Server config:

```
PHP Version                 5.3.29
Database Version            10.1.26-MariaDB
Database Collation          utf8_general_ci
Joomla! Version Joomla!     2.5.28 Stable [ Ember ] 10-December-2014 15:00 GMT
Joomla! Platform Version    Joomla Platform 11.4.0 Stable [ Brian Kernighan ] 03-Jan-2012 00:00 GMT
```

Update: Upon further investigation into the matter, it appears as though going to the home page (after logging in with the component) logs me out immediately. Likely related.

Comment: Can you check your server's PHP error logs? Perhaps some information regarding the issue may be there. Have you made any changes to your site recently? Has your hosting provider made any server related changes? Some hosts have been know to disallow old Joomla versions for security reasons, so most definitely check with them

Comment: Logs don't appear to have anything related to login (component or module based) or the associated functions in them. We did recently change server hosts but that was 2 weeks ago and only today/yesterday has this problem been reported to be happening. I've checked with the host, nothing should be blocking old versions of Joomla. I did however find that going to the home page after logging in logged me out. Will edit to include this detail.

Comment: Hmm, that **is**  odd. Are you using any 3rd party Joomla extensions, such as community builder for users? Any session expire plugins? What version of PHP are you using and what do you have the **session handler** set to in the Joomla Global Configuration?

Comment: The only 3rd party extension I have that may affect users would be Admin Tools Core. Outside of that, only a couple handmade modules/component. PHP version is 5.3.29 and the session handler is set to Database. I tried setting the session handler to None, but that didn't work in the slightest.

Comment: Can you try disabling admin tools?

Comment: No change in functionality

Comment: I dont suppose you can transfer your site to a localhost and test to see if you get the same issue?

Comment: Closing the question. Previous programmer made a mistake when coding the website originally and included legacy code that would perform a login check. The old server's PHP version would bug out and skip this legacy code and the new server had OPCache pick up that slack and continue skipping it. Bug only became apparent once the cache expired. What a lovely waste of time.

Comment: Glad you finally found the solution. Would tou mind adding it as a proper answer below and marking it as accepted when possible? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved after far too many hours of searching. Old legacy code that was buggy and skipped over by the old server somehow went live after a server change. This legacy code somehow forced a logout under very specific conditions.